# Where can I ask questions about a WordPress plugin?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about the code of a WordPress plugin?

Can I ask it on Stack Overflow?

Comment: There's a Wordpress.SE.  You could try there.  The only way to know for sure, though, would be to read their Tour, and double-check.  You can also add the proposed question here, for feedback on where it might be acceptable.

Comment: @fbueckert Thank you, I also found that site.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the site [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Stack Exchange always has a site you need!

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential sites:

- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

The *WordPress Development* site [prohibits questions on third-party plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It seems the intention is that *WordPress Development* site is for those who are **developing plugins** and themes, rather than those who are **developing websites** (using plugins). Those developing websites should probably ask questions on the *Webmasters* site.

So, here’s my rough take on what to do. If your question is about:

- developing a plugin for WordPress, then ask it in *WordPress Development*
- developing a plugin for another plugin, then ask it in whatever forum is provided by the plugin developer
- using a plugin to build a website, then ask it either in *Webmasters* or in the forum provided by the plugin developer